# How do I update a mysql table when a visitor leaves the web page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my problem.

So, I am trying to make my page so that when somone visits the page with PHP

```
if ($_SESSION['signed_in'] == true){
    $sql = "UPDATE
            users
        SET
            user_status = 1
        WHERE
            user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result){
    echo 'fix me!';
    }else{
    }
}
```

Now!

When the user exits or goes to a new page I want the `user_status` to be set back to 0 so when the user enters the site that already has a signed in session it goes back to 1.

How would I get to doing that with PHP or javaScript?
Because even if I have a logout button people will still click exit and they will be logged in forever until they log in and log back out.

Comment: I recommend you checkout Laravel.

Comment: other page means with in your website?

Comment: No I mean a differnt domaine.

Comment: you mean when he logged out?

Comment: You can't get a direct server notification of someone closing their browser.   You have to rely on other methods, like browser-side pinging or websockets.

Comment: Well I have a whos online so select all users in the table with the status of 1 and print them out but when someone leaves the page I want it to set it to 0 because then everyone who was online will be perminintly online.

Comment: Create a logout page and then just do an UPDATE and set their status back to zero soon as they logout; done deal. You don't need JS for that.

Comment: Yeah, thats done but what if people just decide to exit the page insted of clicking the logout button then it just says that they are online all the time

Comment: Sessions don't last indefinitely. PHP's default is an hour if I'm not mistaken, so it won't show that they're always online. You'll need to use a conditional statement to the effect of `if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])){...}` inside all your pages in order to achieve that. You can even decrease the default time.

Comment: Yeah I know but if someone exits it still wont update until they go back onto the page after an hour, and it will say they are on the website looking around indefinintly.

Comment: No. Even throughout multiple sessionned pages, as long as you're using the same session name, it won't show indefinitely and your users will be forced to log back in at some point.

Comment: I understand the point but I am not talking about sessions I am talking about a mysql update every time someone enters or exits the website.

Comment: So heres how it works: User opens webpage> if  the user has a signed in session update his sql table to 1 > if user is not signed in do nothing > if user is signed in and clicks exit ETC, update his table to 0 > repeat.

Comment: You basically answered your own question right there. "Conditional statements". `if(something==something){ // do something }else{ // do something else }`

Comment: YES! Yes I did but how do I get the if user exits the page code to work. Thats all I wanted to know just the code.

Comment: Exit can mean a lot of things. If user leaves your page and goes to Google, if user closes browser, if user clicks a button `unset($_SESSION['user']); session_destroy();` bang; done.

Comment: Yeah But can you transfer that code into javascript.

Comment: Have you tried using trigger ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you do that because if user decides or does not like to load JS, the code will be useless. Do everything server-side as much as possible. You can use session variables in JS, but again I don't recommend it.

Comment: So if you create a session dose that create the same session for everyperson who joins the webpage?

Comment: The session variable is and should be based on the user `id`. I.e.: `$_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];`

Comment: Okay that makes sence. But I have a whos online and it echos all users in a table with user_status 1

Comment: Why not track the time a user is on your website? I mostly do it this way. If there is an inactivity with the user for at least 10 minutes, then automaticly log him off. This means that every page has to update the session with a timestamp in your database. If there is no actiivty for 10 minutes by the user, turn his logged in status to 0.

Comment: Okay can you please post the code to that in the awnsers. thats one of the ways I needed to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use the unload method on your form so that when the user is closing the site, the unload method will be called and then you can set the counter to 0 again.

```
<form onUnload="set0.php">
```

you can do something like that. hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If by leaving you mean using an link on your page, you could just add some server side handling before that. (using a script which changes the status, then does the redirect)

If you mean leaving by entering another address etc., you could still use the `window.unload` event to trigger an ajax call before that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onunload

Comment: Yeah, but the window.unload when I used that it just automaticly set the status to 0.